Cyclic homotopy groups of spheres
The Hopf invariant $h(f)$ of a mapping $f:\mathbb S^{2m-1}\to \mathbb S^m$ is a homotopy invariant that gives information on $\pi_{2m-1}(\mathbb S^m)$ for $m$ even. Namely, there is always $f$ with $h(f)\ne0$ and such an $f$ generates a cyclic infinite group. However, $h(f)$ maybe zero and $f$ not null homotopic. This happen most often, but not for $m=2$ or $m=6$, and then the homotopy group above is cyclic infinite. My question is whether there are other $m$’s for which this happens.

EHP sequence implies that your question is essentially about determining when the suspension homomorphism $\Sigma:\pi_{2m-2}(S^{m-1})\to\pi_{2m-1}(S^m)$ is trivial. Maybe these are still open problems?

One can use rational homotopy theory to calculate $\pi_n\otimes\mathbb Q$. This will pick out any infinite cyclic components. The only nonzero ones are $\pi_n(S^n)\cong\mathbb Q$ and $\pi_{4n-1}(S_{2n})\cong\mathbb Q$. So the only groups that have an infinite cyclic component are the ones detected by the hopf invariant.

Thanks, and that’s true, but misses my point: when there are finite components.

My question was very modest, and checking some others on unstable homotopy groups of spheres in OverFlow I've found that for $m=30$ the homotopy group is cyclic infinite. See:
N. Oda, On the 2-components of the unstable homotopy groups of spheres Parts I, II, Proc. Japan Acad. 53, Ser. A(1977), no. 6/7, 202-205/215-218,
where if I understand well it says $\pi_{59}(\mathbb S^{30})=\mathbb Z$.
And I guess my question was quite naive as by an outsider to the area.
